# cakephp validate against database

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.x

I need to check to see if a submitted date range overlaps any existing date ranges in the database

I know how to do the check but i'm wondering where to do it and if there's a best practice for it

It seems a bit odd to communicate with the database in a validator somehow

Is this something that should be done in the controller maybe?

I was thinking about just calling a finder in the 'Add' action of the controller and returning true/false depending on whether it returns any rows or not

Anybody done this?

Would really appreciate a few pointers folks

Answer (score 0):

I've been told application rules are the way to do this

I haven't tried it yet but i thought i'd pass on the info

Cheers